# api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveExceptio in ANroid

Tags: android

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buddymi_user_app:debugCompileClasspath'. in Android
my App Does not Working And Run

i try So many things And Fix Try To From StackOverflow